# Alternatives to the "on the one hand... on the other hand" construct

Tags: synonyms, discourse-markers

Can anyone suggest any alternatives to the "on the one hand... on the other hand" construct?

Example: (On the one hand/alternative) I like product A. (On the other hand/alternative) product B also appeals to me strongly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- I like product A. [*Alternatively*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/alternatively), product B also appeals to me.
- I like product A. *Then again*, product B also appeals to me.
- I like product A. *But then*, product B also appeals to me.
- *While* I like product A, product B also appeals to me.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about similar phrases but I was actually hoping for an expression that consists of a part in both the first as well as in the second sentence. This conveys the right meaning though :).

Comment: @dreamer - You can start the pair with *"While..."* and cut out the 'middleman'.

Comment: Good answer. Our 'on the one hand...the other' derives from the ancient Greek 'ho men...ho de' and is still regarded as rhetorical, I think. The alternatives suggested above are less formal, so it really depends whether you are (for example) debating, or being more conversational.

Comment: @user103188 Contrastive constructions of this kind are more or less universal. The English expression in no way ‘derives’ from the Greek expression, they just happen to be fairly parallel.

Answer (score 3):

The formal [discourse marker](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/soc/al/learning_english/leap/grammar/discourse/) used by the OP; ["on the one hand ... on the other hand"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/on-the-one-hand-on-the-other-hand) expresses two *contrasting*  ideas, opinions or facts. In view of this fact, I suggest the following alternatives:

- **Although** I like product A, product B also appeals to me strongly.
- I like product A, **although** product B is also appealing.
- I prefer product A; **however**, product B is said to be more appealing.
- **Even though** I prefer product A; product B appeals to most people.
- I prefer product A, **but** product B also has great appeal.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I like product A, I prefer product B.