# A phrase or word that is like "on the other hand" but for opposite ideas supporting the same argument

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, contradiction

A sentence such as "I should go cycling because my head says it is good for my longevity and on the other hand in my heart I am passionate about it" does not make much sense.

On the one hand the usual head versus heart comparison is intended to provide alternative views, on the other hand in this case the head and the heart premises support the same conclusion. Hence, the second sentence uses "on the other hand" correctly (in terms of logic) but the former does not, since there is no real contradiction.

What is a suitable alternative to "on the other hand", to emphasize the two different perspectives that nevertheless support the same conclusion?

Comment: *moreover*? *furthermore*?

Comment: Those are what I would normally use, but I want to emphasize the two supporting arguments appeal to seemingly opposed values (e.g., head versus heart).

Comment: Simultaneously? Surprisingly? Counter-intuitively? Even *hey*:  "and, hey, in my heart I am passionate."

Comment: *My head tells me that… Similarly, my heart also says I am passionate about cycling*. You're not expressing opposing views, both your head and heart agree that cycling is a good thing.

Comment: I'm expressing ideas that are often used to support contradictory consequents, so I'd like to make light of that whilst using the two views to support the same consequent. Each supporting claim is also of equal value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternatives to the "on the one hand... on the other hand" construct](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216956/alternatives-to-the-on-the-one-hand-on-the-other-hand-construct)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a word that suggests that normally-opposing sources agree. Consider *even*.

> **even** *adverb*
>   1 Used to emphasize something surprising or extreme.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/even)

In your example, you can say:

- I should go cycling because my head says it is good for my longevity; even my heart is passionate about it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition / additionally / moreover / as well as / not to mention / and ... as well / furthermore / also?